# Specify build verbosity for command line build using devenv

Tags: command-line, compilation, devenv

Is there a way to specify build verbosity for command line build using devenv?

I'm trying to make a test that builds our solution twice and the second time it builds it should output:

Build: 55 succeeded, 0 failed, 69 up-to-date, 1 skipped

But it should actually be 0 succeeded, x up-to-date.

I have the test running but ideally, I'd specify to build with verbosity = diagnostic for the second build so I can see why things are rebuilding.

I know msbuild has a verbosity flag, I don't think there is a way to set build verbosity using devenv, unless someone can give me a sneaky way.

I know that for building we generally should use msbuild, but I think devenv seems to do a better job of avoiding recompiling things that have already been compiled.  So I want to use it for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't do it using devenv. But you could if you switch to msbuild.